# How to distinguish antMatchers with path variable from the rest of context path

Tags: spring, spring-security

I have two paths:

```
/api/posts/{postId}
/api/posts/myPosts
```

I want to permit all for the first path and protect second path with role USER.

I tried below patterns but when I add first pattern, the second stop working (user can GET *myPosts* even if he doesn't have USER role). 
What I'm doing  wrong?

```
.antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/api/posts/{postId}").permitAll()
.antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/api/posts/myPosts").hasRole("USER")
```

Comment: Switch the lines. Order matters.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in the order of your rules. Reversing the order will work.

```
.antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/api/posts/myPosts").hasRole("USER")
.antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/api/posts/{postId}").permitAll()
```

Answer (score -1):

The thing here is that you have to specify that all the paths are authenticated since it is not the default implementation of the HttpSecurity object.

```
.antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/api/posts/{postId}").permitAll()
.antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/api/posts/myPosts").hasRole("USER")
.anyRequest().authenticated()
```

I suggest to check this [link](https://www.baeldung.com/java-config-spring-security) here by the guys over at baeldung, they give a brief intro to Spring Security.

Comment: Your answer is wrong. Did you try it?

Comment: I have already this line : .anyRequest().authenticated(). @AnantGoswami's answer is good.